# Why is C++ not updated as frequently as Java?

Tags: java, c++

Java was last revised in 2020, while C++ had it's update back in 2017

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: That's a total non sequitur. With your numbers, it could be that Java is updated every 20 years (next time 2040), and C++ every 4 years (2021, 2025, 2029, 2033, 2037, 2041).

Comment: In general, standards committees take however long they take to do their work.  The first draft of the HTML5 specification was completed in 2007.  The final draft of Version 1.0 wasn't "recommended" until 2014.  Of course, browser manufacturers incorporated HTML5 features long before that, a process of de-facto standardization that paved the way for the "final" spec.

Comment: @gnasher729 whatever you meant to say doesn't make any sense unlike what _gnat_ did, pointed out a mistake that i lacked research. or maybe you were in a hurry to flag this before anyone else did

Comment: @drac_o: Read OP’s claim and their purported evidence.

Comment: @gnasher729 I'm the OP

Comment: You get @gnasher729's point though, right?  This is, you understand that having updated more _recently_ doesn't imply updating more _frequently_?  I ask because you said gnasher729's point **"_doesn't make any sense_"**, but gnasher729's point seems pretty clear to me, so just curious about where the confusion might be.

Comment: To note it, a [**_non-sequitur_**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur_(fallacy)) is a claim (like Java updating more frequently) being supported by an argument (like Java having updated more recently) from which it doesn't follow.  (Sorry if you knew that; I wasn't sure if the term may've been the source of confusion.)

Comment: Also, Java's a strange language to pick. It's incredibly conservative and slow moving. Just wait until you see the pace of change in Rust, Golang and Swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ is first and foremost, a specification managed by the ISO. It takes time to build alignment so that a draft specification will pass the vote. It also takes time for that specification to actually be implemented by compilers. Too frequent releases are counterproductive if you want compilers to make new features available in practice. So, C++ has settled on a three-year rhythm which ensures a predictable flow of new features. The C++ 20 version is currently in the process of standardization, but drafts are already available.

Java is owned by Oracle, and Oracle is in the business of selling licenses. Upgrading every half year is not tenable in most contexts, so if you want stability you have to pay Oracle for support (or use non-Oracle implementations). The more frequent updates starting with Java 9 also have to be viewed against the history of a quite unstable and slow update rhythm before that, which led to a stagnation of the language, especially compared with competitors such as C#. Java 9 is also notable because its module system introduced significant backwards compatibility problems. A more frequent release train doesn't mean more frequent upgrades. In practice, both the C++ and Java worlds are largely using versions from 2014 now, if they aren't completely stuck on legacy versions (enterprise software is “fun”).

Comment: Yeah, it looks like Oracle is shipping roughly one sixth the features in one sixth the time, so it's more or less a wash. And most of those are tiny features. The last big ones were lambdas, indy, and modules, and they were all shipped on the older, longer cadence, and took years to design and develop. The new big features are value types, reified generics, and unified type system, and I don't see any of them on the horizon anytime soon.

Answer (score 5):

Oracle has only recently increased the release cadence. Before that, there could also be many years between Java releases.

Note that the fact that Java releases have a higher frequency than C++ releases does not mean that the rate of innovation is necessarily higher. In fact, the way that Oracle was able to change the release cadence from "many years" to "every 6 months" was simply by shipping fewer features and making fewer changes.

So, they ship fewer features faster, but the total rate is still comparable.

Another difference is that features that are under discussion by the ISO C++ committee are shipped by compiler vendors long before they become part of the standard. Plus, there is the Boost project, whose specific purpose it is to test out new library features outside of the standards process before they get introduced into the standard.

In Java, there is generally no way of testing new features ahead of time, unless you compile a patched version of the JDK yourself.